# How can i perform replacing a text after extract in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the numbers and characters (%) to "**Voted**" in javascript but the problem is Number always changed in a random manner

**i have this:**

```
VOTED = VOTED.replace('100%','Voted');
```

so anyone know how to solve this and thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are you trying to replace? Every Number and % character that occurs in string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex with `String.replace(regex, replace)`

```js
const myText = '15% test';

const newText = myText.replace(/\d+%/, 'Voted');
console.log(newText);
```

Comment: boom thanks mate <3 you made my day it's working perfectly :) and thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @kannankr No problem ! Next time, think about reading the docs ;)